# finding and calling a function on ajax loaded html with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a main div

```
<ul id="main">
   <li id="A100">
             <ul class="slides">
                     <li><img1></li>
                     <li><img2></li>
             </ul>
   </li> 
   <li id="A99">
             <ul class="slides">
                     <li><img1></li>
                     <li><img2></li>
             </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I run the slider code on it

```
$("#main li").each(function() 
    { 
         $(this).slides({
             height      : 320,           
                 showmarkers : false
          });
    });
```

When I load more

with ajax, How can I run the slider code on just that new

before I add it to the main div? my ajax returned data looks like this.

```
<li id="A98">
             <ul class="slides">
                     <li><img1></li>
                     <li><img2></li>
             </ul>
   </li> 
   <li id="A97">
             <ul class="slides">
                     <li><img1></li>
                     <li><img2></li>
             </ul>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in the ajax success handler. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    ....
}).done(function(response){
    if(response != ""){
        var newItems = $('<ul>' + response + '</ul>').children('li');
        newItems.each(function(i, val){
            $("#main").append(val);
            $(val).find('li').slides({
                 height      : 320,           
                 showmarkers : false
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have var k=A98 with me, when I start the ajax call. When ajax response comes in, I can add it to #main. Then can I do something like, find all <li> which are children of main (and not those inside these <li>s) after the li with id = "k" and perform the slider function? Sorry, I am not too good with jquery.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The code in the answer will apply the slides function to each new li that comes on the Ajax response.

Comment: by your method, the parent <li> is being treated as a slide. I only want the <li>s inside <ul> inside the top <li>s to be slided. I am not sure why.

Comment: Is it possible to add the response to #main, and then call the slide function on the newly added <li>s alone? I can call it all the whole #main but it is messing  up some other things. I am not sure how to use the nextAll() function

Comment: See my edit, by changing the selector to `li li` it will now apply to the sub li's. So 98 won't be affected, but it's descendant li's will be.

Comment: thanks for your patience, but that edit did not help. here why. I need to preserve the html structure inside my #main for the slides to work, and your last update added only one <li> <ul> <li> to it.